# UIActivityViewController Print: how to dismiss the Print view controller programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` for sharing images, I need to dismiss all the modal view controllers when app goes to background, currently I'm observing the notification when app goes to background, and do the followings:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]
```

It works for the Email view controller, but the Print view controller is not dismissed. I also tried to have a symbolic breakpoint on `[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]` but when Print is selected the Print screen's presented the breakpoint does not catch it. I really don't know where the Print screen's presented.

Anyone has experience on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more code here?

Comment: If you presented your UIActivityViewController from viewController or navigationController you need the first dismiss it. I think you need add a property with UIActivityViewController and after user will go to background you will call something like this `[self.activityVIewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]` or you can find all presented view controllers through `[self.navigationController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but Try this code

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it. To me it doesn't feel like the navigation pop can dismiss it though.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code,

```
[presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: The Email screen is dismissed, it's the Print screen that's not dismissed.

Comment: Try change the mainComposer for to Print

Comment: But I was using UIActivityViewController instead of the mail composer VC.